# DT table in Shiny (overriding custom css) - How to color the whole row based on a value in a specific column?

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, dt

I am trying to color the top two rows differently from the rest of the table as it contains control samples. The table is made using DT for Shiny app.

**Desired output:**

[image]

**Actual output:**

[image]

**The code:**

```
output$table <- renderDataTable({
dt <- dt %>% datatable(rownames=FALSE, class="table table-hover row-border", extensions = c( 'FixedHeader'),
                options = list( scrollX = TRUE, pageLength = -1,dom = 'Btpl', ordering = TRUE, 
                                dom="ft",
                                lengthMenu = list(c(10,25,-1),
                                                  c(10,25,"All")), 
                                columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE, targets=c(7,8)))
                )) %>%
          formatStyle('Sample', 
                      fontWeight ='bold', 
                      backgroundColor = styleEqual(c("Positive control", "Negative control"), 
                      c("#fcf4d9", "#fcf4d9")))
})
```

I have tried adding `target = "row"` argument but it doesn't work. I also tried to use `styleRow()` instead of `styleEqual()` but this resulted in error "coercion of NA values".

**Update:**

The default bakcground colors are specified in tags$style that is why it doesn't work using format style:

```
  tags$style(HTML(sprintf('table.dataTable tbody tr {background-color:  %1$s !important; color:  %2$s !important;}', 
                          table_col,font_col_dark)))
```

I am not that familiar with this expression, but is it possible to specify the bakcground color for controls in tags instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `target = 'row'` should be the solution:

[image]

**Code:**

```r
# Data
dt <- tibble(Well = 1:5, Sample = c("Positive control", "Negative control", "Sample 1", "Sample 2", "Sample 3"), Result = 10:14)

# Table
dt %>% datatable(rownames=FALSE, class="table table-hover row-border", extensions = c( 'FixedHeader'),
                 options = list( scrollX = TRUE, pageLength = -1,dom = 'Btpl', ordering = TRUE, 
                                 dom="ft",
                                 lengthMenu = list(c(10,25,-1),
                                                   c(10,25,"All")), 
                                 columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE, targets=c(7,8)))
                 )) %>%
    formatStyle('Sample', 
                fontWeight ='bold',
                target = 'row',
                backgroundColor = styleEqual(c("Positive control", "Negative control"), 
                                             c("#fcf4d9", "#fcf4d9")))
```

**Update:**

You might control the background color by using some helper vectors instead:

```r
# Data
dt <- tibble(Well = 1:5, Sample = c("Positive control", "Negative control", "Sample 1", "Sample 2", "Sample 3"), Result = 10:14)

# Helper
id_helper <- unique(dt$Sample)
color_helper <- ifelse(id_helper %in% c("Positive control", "Negative control"), '#fcf4d9', 'blue')

# Table
dt %>% datatable(rownames=FALSE, class="table table-hover row-border", extensions = c( 'FixedHeader'),
                 options = list( scrollX = TRUE, pageLength = -1,dom = 'Btpl', ordering = TRUE, 
                                 dom="ft",
                                 lengthMenu = list(c(10,25,-1),
                                                   c(10,25,"All")), 
                                 columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE, targets=c(7,8)))
                 )) %>%
    formatStyle('Sample', 
                fontWeight ='bold',
                target = 'row',
                backgroundColor = styleEqual(id_helper, 
                                             color_helper))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for confirmation! Your answer is correc I believe, however, this code doens't work for me as default background color is set with tags$style (just found out). Is there a way to override this or specify within tags$style? Check updated question.

Comment: My best solution would be to set the background color in `formatStyle`, too. See update. Hope it'll work, or you'll need to see what other's come up with.

Comment: I managed to replicate this solution but not in my shiny app. I think it overrides the `formatSyle` argument `target = "row"`. Basically, if I include this argument table remains the same and if I exclude only that particular cell color changes. I will accept your answer as it does answer my question theoritcally, but need to figure out what overrides the `formatSyle` and how to fix it since I can't really provide a minimal example of my complicated app.

Comment: Your suggested solution works! I found another place where row colors are adjusted based on another column overriding the postitive/negative controls colors.